# Query to select rows where JSONB arrays have variable lengths

Tags: arrays, postgresql, query-optimization, jsonb

I have a table (`t`) which contains a column (`c`) of JSONB objects, each containing an array (`a`) with a varying length between 1-10 (inclusive). I need to build a query that selects 1000 rows from `t` where `c` includes 100 random rows of **each** possible length of `a`. What would be the most concise way to write this query? My current query structure looks like this:

```
WITH length_1 AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM t
    WHERE JSONB_ARRAY_LENGTH(c -> 'a') = 1
    ORDER BY RANDOM()
    LIMIT 100
),
length_2 AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM t
    WHERE JSONB_ARRAY_LENGTH(c -> 'a') = 2
    ORDER BY RANDOM()
    LIMIT 100
)
...
SELECT *
FROM length_1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM length_2
...
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the current and the expected output are the same. The question is asking for a simpler way to write a functional query. No data is required. Your comment offers no value to this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a window function to label each row with a row number within its partition, then use an outer select to limit to 100 for each partition.

```
select * from (
    select t.*, row_number() over (partition by jsonb_array_length(c->'a') order by random()) as rn from t
) foo  where rn<=100;
```

The two levels are needed because you can't use a window function in a WHERE or a HAVING.